# Find day difference between two dates (excluding weekend days)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Hi i am using jquery-ui datepicker to select date and [date.js](http://mattkruse.com/javascript/date/date.js) to find difference between 2 dates.

Right now the problem is I want to exclude weekend days from calculation (saturday and sunday). How should i do that?

For example the user select start date (13/8/2010) and end date (16/8/2010). Since 14/8/2010 and 15/8/2010 is in week days, instead of 4 days total, i want it to be only 2 days.

This is the code im using right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#startdate, #enddate").change(function() {       

    var d1 = $("#startdate").val();
    var d2 = $("#enddate").val();

            var minutes = 1000*60;
            var hours = minutes*60;
            var day = hours*24;

            var startdate1 = getDateFromFormat(d1, "d-m-y");
            var enddate1 = getDateFromFormat(d2, "d-m-y");

            var days = 1 + Math.round((enddate1 - startdate1)/day);             

    if(days>0)
    { $("#noofdays").val(days);}
    else
    { $("#noofdays").val(0);}


    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe someone else can help you converting this function into JQuery's framework...

I found this function [here](http://snipplr.com/view/4086/calculate-business-days-between-two-dates/).

```js
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
  var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
  if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
  var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
  var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
  iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
  if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
  iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

  // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
  iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

  if (iWeekday1 < iWeekday2) { //Equal to makes it reduce 5 days
    iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
  } else {
    iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
  }

  iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

  return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}

var date1 = new Date("August 11, 2010 11:13:00");
var date2 = new Date("August 16, 2010 11:13:00");
alert(calcBusinessDays(date1, date2));
```

### ## EDITED ##

If you want to use it with your that format just:

Your code will look like:

```js
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
  var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
  if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
  var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
  var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
  iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
  if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
  iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

  // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
  iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

  if (iWeekday1 < iWeekday2) { //Equal to makes it reduce 5 days
    iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
  } else {
    iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
  }

  iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

  return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}


$("#startdate, #enddate").change(function() {

  var d1 = $("#startdate").val();
  var d2 = $("#enddate").val();

  var minutes = 1000 * 60;
  var hours = minutes * 60;
  var day = hours * 24;

  var startdate1 = new Date(d1);
  var enddate1 = new Date(d2);


  var newstartdate = new Date();
  newstartdate.setFullYear(startdate1.getYear(), startdate1.getMonth(), startdate1.getDay());
  var newenddate = new Date();
  newenddate.setFullYear(enddate1.getYear(), enddate1.getMonth(), enddate1.getDay());
  var days = calcBusinessDays(newstartdate, newenddate);
  if (days > 0) {
    $("#noofdays").val(days);
  } else {
    $("#noofdays").val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Start Date
 <input type="date" id="startdate" value="2019-03-03"/>
</label>

<label>End Date
 <input type="date" id="enddate" value="2019-03-06"/>
</label>

<label>N. of days
 <output id="noofdays"/>
</label>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. will give this code a try and hope can solve my problem :)

Comment: To use it in your code use stardate1 and enddate1 as the parameters for the calcBusinessDays(date, date) function...

Comment: the script doesnt accept this date format (11-08-2010). trying to figure out now.

Comment: By the way, the function getDateFromFormat return a javascript Date object right?... because the function i've just posted accept Date objects as parameters

Comment: thanks i get it work although the code is bit different. anyway thank very much for your help. I have been stucked by this problem for 2 days until i found stackoverflow and your great help.

Comment: +1 for posting a reference to the original code!  I actually didn't see that when I looked at the post originally.  The +1 is also because the code IS faster than my solution, but not by much :)

Comment: `setFullYear` accepts only a year as parameter... better pass those params to the `new Date()` instead..

Comment: @GarisMSuero calcBusinessDays it does not work for any two dates, try it with '20140328' and '20140404'; the result is 0, which is wrong; this happens because of UTC offset; please check in this post, Michael Liu's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @FlaviaObreja I've just tried and it returned 6 days. Please notice that the right format is 2014-03-28 and 2014-04-04 http://jsbin.com/ufoze4/318/

Comment: @GarisMSuero i think my example worked for you because you have other date start for the daylight saving time. Please check the following jsfiddle where i made two examples, one using the begining of daylight saving date in US and the other one is for european union, to cover both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/ma34r/

Comment: This script doesn't work properly. It shows 1 day when starting in a sunday and ending the Friday ahead. [Reproduction of the bug here](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gmkLwg/)

Comment: It is giving wrong result.If you are selecting start date " 06-11-2015" and end date " 06-18-2015"..it is giving the result as 1. It should be 5

Comment: I modified your solution so it would work if the start date was a saturday or a sunday.

Answer (score 17):

To do this, you should NOT search all days between these dates !

It's not complicated, look some evident assumptions:

1. All full-week has 7-days.
2. Which 2 are weekend-days.
3. And which 5 are business-day.

Evident conclusions:

1. Look all days is loss of time.
2. Check what day is weekend to all week is loss of time.

---

Without tedious explanation.. let me show the code:

```js
function getBusinessDateCount (startDate, endDate) {
    var elapsed, daysBeforeFirstSaturday, daysAfterLastSunday;
    var ifThen = function (a, b, c) {
        return a == b ? c : a;
    };

    elapsed = endDate - startDate;
    elapsed /= 86400000;

    daysBeforeFirstSunday = (7 - startDate.getDay()) % 7;
    daysAfterLastSunday = endDate.getDay();

    elapsed -= (daysBeforeFirstSunday + daysAfterLastSunday);
    elapsed = (elapsed / 7) * 5;
    elapsed += ifThen(daysBeforeFirstSunday - 1, -1, 0) + ifThen(daysAfterLastSunday, 6, 5);

    return Math.ceil(elapsed);
}

function calc() {
  let start = document.querySelector('#startDate').value,
      end = document.querySelector('#endDate').value,
      result = getBusinessDateCount(new Date(start), new Date(end));
  document.querySelector('#result').value = result;
}
```

```html
Start date: <input type="date" id="startDate" value="2020-01-04"><br>
End date: <input type="date" id="endDate" value="2020-01-06"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Get business days"><br>
Business days: <input id="result" readonly>
```

You can test it yourself with any dates.

I just want to notice that [this code ONLY consumed 0.43 sec](https://ideone.com/XnTcMK) between dates from 2000 to 2015... It is much more fast than some other codes.

Hope it helps...

Nice coding !!

Comment: It doesn't count properly when starting on a weekend [Reproduction of the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/ho02j7yt/). Its counting 3 days when it should be 5.

Comment: @Alvaro. Many thanks for the reply.. I've updated the function.. Check if it works for you now

Comment: Thanks a lot for it, it seems to be working properly now!

Comment: Thanks for this great bit of code. There is, however, an error. You've defined `daysBeforeFirstSaturday` on the first line, but you are referencing `daysBeforeFirstSunday` throughout the function. I assume this is a typo.

Comment: This doesn't take daylight savings into account. If your date range includes a change in timezone offset the result will be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I would do it

```
function getDays(d1, d2) {
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
    var d1_days = parseInt(d1.getTime()/one_day) - 1;
    var d2_days = parseInt(d2.getTime()/one_day);
    var days = (d2_days - d1_days);
    var weeks = (d2_days - d1_days) / 7;
    var day1 = d1.getDay();
    var day2 = d2.getDay();
    if (day1 == 0) {
        days--;
    } else if (day1 == 6) {
        days-=2;
    }
    if (day2 == 0) {
       days-=2;
    } else if (day2 == 6) {
       days--;
    }
    days -= parseInt(weeks) * 2;
    alert(days);
}

getDays(new Date("June 8, 2004"),new Date("February 6, 2010"));
```

**EDIT**
To clarify my comment to @keenebec...
That solution will work for small date differences quite nicely and is easy to understand.  But take something as "short" as a 6 year span and you can see a remarkable difference in speed.

http://jsfiddle.net/aSvxv/

I included all 3 answers and the original answer is indeed the fastest, but not by much and the trade off for a few microseconds of execution is somewhat trivial to me in favor of readability.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The one by Garis has bugs starting and finishing on weekends ([reproduction of Garis bug](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gmkLwg/))

Comment: This is an old post, but was wondering if there's any way to modify this to take time also into consideration and provide the difference in days as a fraction - Ex: Difference between 2 timestamps is 2.35 days after excluding weekends

Comment: Failing when starting in Thusday and finishing in Monday. [Reproduction of the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/4ajs66qa/). There are 3 working days and its reporting 5.

Comment: To fix the bug where if day2 is less than day1:
`if (day2 < day1) weeks++;`

Answer (score 4):

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf())
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

function getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate) {
    var count = 0;
    var curDate = startDate;
    while (curDate <= endDate) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        var isWeekend = (dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0); 
        if(!isWeekend)
           count++;
        curDate = curDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return count;
}



//Usage
var startDate = new Date('7/16/2015');
var endDate = new Date('7/20/2015');
var numOfDays = getBusinessDatesCount(startDate,endDate);
jQuery('div#result').text(numOfDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like too much work to me. I'd rather let the computer do the heavy lifting-
//

```
Date.bizdays= function(d1, d2){
    var bd= 0, dd, incr=d1.getDate();
    while(d1<d2){
        d1.setDate(++incr);
        dd= d1.getDay();
        if(dd%6)++bd;
    }
    return bd;
}

//test

var day1= new Date(2010, 7, 11), day2= new Date(2010, 7, 31);

alert(Date.bizdays(day1, day2))
```

Comment: this is definitely a very feasible solution.  However, it does mean a "fairly" high number of iterations which may or may not be significant overhead on the client's machine, but fine answer none-the-less.

Comment: How about losing the biggest chunk of the work by getting floor((d2-d1)/7)? That gives you the number of weeks, which will all contain 5 business days. Then use your roll-forward to finish it off.

Answer (score 1):

To understand way.,

---

1. Actual days = 14
2. weeks for Actual days = 14/7=2
3. Weekends per week=2
4. Total weekends=2*weeks for days

---

So apply this ,

```
 $('#EndDate').on('change', function () {
            var start = $('#StartDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var end = $('#EndDate').datepicker('getDate');
            if (start < end) {
                var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

                var Weeks=Math.round(days)/7;

                var totalWeekends=Math.round(Weeks)*2;

                var puredays=Math.round(days)-totalWeekends;

                $('#days').text(Math.round(puredays) + "Working Days");


            }
            else {
alert("");
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: If I want to get output like { week1: 3 working days , week2: 5 working days ....}

Comment: then you need to set calculation to find out like : Total days / 7 = weeks rest is days .

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** Most answers here don't actually work if the start date (or sometimes the end date) is a saturday or sunday. I took the accepted response and modified it so that this issue is resolved now:

```
    var dateDiff;
    if (dateTo < dateFrom) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
    var dateFromDayOrig = dateFrom.getDay(); // day of week
    var dateToDayOrig = dateTo.getDay();
    var dateFromDay = (dateFromDayOrig == 0) ? 7 : dateFromDayOrig; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    var dateToDay = (dateToDayOrig == 0) ? 7 : dateToDayOrig;
    dateFromDay = (dateFromDay > 5) ? 5 : dateFromDay; // only count weekdays
    dateToDay = (dateToDay > 5) ? 5 : dateToDay;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    var weekDifference = Math.floor((dateTo.getTime() - dateFrom.getTime()) / 604800000);

    if (dateFromDay <= dateToDay) {
        dateDiff = (weekDifference * 5) + (dateToDay - dateFromDay);
    } else {
        dateDiff = ((weekDifference + 1) * 5) - (dateFromDay - dateToDay);
    }

    // fix: remove one day if it's saturday or sunday
    if (dateFromDayOrig >= 6 || dateFromDayOrig == 0) {
    dateDiff--;
    }

    return (dateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
```

Comment: i've been using this code for a while and it's been mostly very reliable, but i've now realised there's a flaw where it gives a weekdifference of 0 if theres 7 days difference between the dates

` dateTo: Tue May 11 2021 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` 

` dateFrom: Tue May 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` 

` weekDifference: 0days`

Comment: eg: startDate: 1620319036957 endDate: 1620860400000 weekdifference returns: 0

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be few issues with the response that has been marked as solution.

- The statement setFullYear() is returning incorrect value if I choose start date as 06/11/2015. So instead, the startDate1 and endDate1 can be directly passed to the function.
- If the start date is Saturday or Sunday, still the code is counting it(iWeekday1) as 5 days
- If the end date is Saturday or Sunday, still the code is counting it(iWeekday2) as 5 days. But these 5 days already get counted in the iweeks calculation. 

   So instead of 
  *iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays

  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;*
  it should be
  iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? **0** : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
  iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? **0** : iWeekday2;
- The last IF condition should be executed when start and end date day is same like both are on same day, the date could be different
  if (iWeekday1 <**=** iWeekday2)
- The condition that adjusts if both days are weekends can be removed
  **iDateDiff -= iAdjust**
- Lastly, the +1 should be done only if start and end date falls on weekdays. Currently, it is adding in both the cases. 
  return (iDateDiff + 1);**//Add condition to apply only if both days are weekdays**

--can't comment on that answer as I do not have that reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

I get it work with this code. Note that the function is from [date.js](http://mattkruse.com/javascript/date/date.js) and businessday js (thanks to Garis Suero). Start Date 11-08-2010 End Date 16-08-2010 will result 4 days of leave.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#startdate, #enddate").change(function() {       

    var d1 = $("#startdate").val();
    var d2 = $("#enddate").val();

            var minutes = 1000*60;
            var hours = minutes*60;
            var day = hours*24;

            var startdate1 = getDateFromFormat(d1, "d-m-y");
            var enddate1 = getDateFromFormat(d2, "d-m-y");

            var days = calcBusinessDays(new Date(startdate1),new Date(enddate1));             

    if(days>0)
    { $("#noofdays").val(days);}
    else
    { $("#noofdays").val(0);}


    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did

```
function calcbusinessdays()
{
    for(var c=0,e=0,d=new Date($("#startdate").val()),a=(new Date($("#enddate").val())-d)/864E5;0<=a;a--)
    {
        var b=new Date(d);
        b.setDate(b.getDate()+a);
        1==Math.ceil(b.getDay()%6/6)?c++:e++
    }
    $("#noofdays").html(c)
};
```

`c` is weekdays, `e` is weekends

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
 var currentDate;
                            selectFlixbleDates = [];
                            var monToSatDateFilter=[];
                            currentDate=new Date(date);
                            while(currentDate){
                                console.log("currentDate"+currentDate);
                                if(new Date(currentDate).getDay()!=0){
                                    selectFlixbleDates.push(currentDate)
                                }
                                if(selectFlixbleDates.length==$scope.numberOfDatePick)
                                {

                                    break;
                                }
                                currentDate=addDays(currentDate,1);

                            }
                            for (var i = 0; i < selectFlixbleDates.length; i++) {

                                //  console.log(between[i]);
                                monToSatDateFilter.push((selectFlixbleDates[i].getMonth() + 1) + '/' + selectFlixbleDates[i].getDate() + '/' + selectFlixbleDates[i].getFullYear());

                            }
                            var endDate=monToSatDateFilter.slice(-1).pop();
                            var space =monToSatDateFilter.join(', ');
                            var sdfs= document.getElementById("maxPicks").value =space;
                            $scope.$apply(function() {
                                $scope.orderEndDate=monToSatDateFilter.slice(-1).pop()
                                $scope.orderStartDate=monToSatDateFilter[0];
                            });
                            document.getElementById("startDateEndDate").innerHTML =$scope.orderStartDate+ ' TO ' +$scope.orderEndDate
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Angular framework and Moment.js library to implement the solution.
My solution covers all the cases.

```
this.daysInBetween = this.endMoment.diff(this.startMoment, 'days') + 1;
this.weeksInBetween = this.endMoment.diff(this.startMoment, 'weeks');
this.weekDays = this.daysInBetween - (this.weeksInBetween * 2);

if ( (this.startMoment.day() === 0 && this.endMoment.day() === 6) ||
 (this.startMoment.day() > this.endMoment.day()) ) {
  // IF ONE WEEKEND WAS MISSED
  this.weekDays-=2;
} else if ( this.startMoment.day() <= this.endMoment.day() &&
( this.startMoment.day() === 0 || this.startMoment.day() === 6 ||
  this.endMoment.day() === 0 || this.endMoment.day() === 6) ) {
  // IF EITHER OF DAYS WAS A WEEKEND
  this.weekDays--;
}
```

Live Demo: 
[Calculate number of weekdays](https://stackblitz.com/edit/weekdays?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

> I am currently working on a blog to write about my approach to this
>   specific problem. I will post the link to the blog on the comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** Most answers here don't actually work if the start date (or sometimes the end date) is a saturday or sunday.
For example: if your start and end date are

- *Saturday to Sunday* or vice versa
- or *Saturday to Saturday*
- or *Sunday to Sunday*

So, here is the modified answer from the accepted answer

```
function calculateBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) {

var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
if (dDate2 < dDate1) {
    return -1;
}

var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay();
var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();

iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 === 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1;
iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 === 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;

if (iWeekday1 > 5 && iWeekday2 <= 6) {
    iWeekday1 = 0;
    iAdjust = 1;
}
iWeekday2 = (iWeekday1 === 0 && iWeekday2 === 6) ? 0 : iWeekday2;

if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1;

iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1;
iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;
iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000);

if (iWeeks===0 && iWeekday1===0 && iWeekday2===0 
    && (dDate2.getTime() !== dDate1.getTime()) ) {
    iWeeks = 1;
}

if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
    iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
} else {
    iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
}
iDateDiff -= iAdjust
return (iDateDiff + 1);
```

}