# Calculate business days between two days should exclude holidays

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to calculate the business days between two days excluding holidays [an array]. [This code helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464346/100747) calculating the business days, but it doesn't exclude holidays:

```
<script>
        function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
        var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
        if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
        var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
        var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
        if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

        // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
        iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

        if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
          iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
        } else {
          iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
        }

        iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

        return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
    }
 </script>
```

List of holidays:

```
natDays = [
  [1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'],
  [4, 27, 'za'], [5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'],
  [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], [9, 7, 'br'],
  [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']
];

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
      if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1
          && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
        return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
      }
    }
  return [true, ''];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date.js is an extremely handy date library with all kinds of convenience methods like `between()` that will greatly simplify your problem.

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#between