# DateJS - Do Not Include Weeknds

Tags: javascript, datejs

I have DateJS set up on my website to give users the ability to know when they will receive their package.

I am utilizing [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) script to do this.

I need to modify the script so that it does not include weekends when estimating the delivery day.

For example, today (Friday), if someone selects one of the following:

Next Day Air: it should show Monday, not Saturday
Two Day Air: It should show Tuesday, not Sunday
Three Day Air: It should show Wednesday, not Monday

Help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <th>Shipping Method</th>
          <th>Estimated Delivery</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>3 Day Select</td>
            <td><span class="fromDate-1"></span>
             <script>
               var fromDate = Date.today().addDays(3);
                if (fromDate.is().saturday() || fromDate.is().sunday())
                 fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
                 $('.fromDate-1').html(fromDate.toString('dddd MMMM dS'));
             </script>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2nd Day Air</td>
            <td><span class="fromDate-2"></span>
              <script>
                var fromDate = Date.today().addDays(2);
                if (fromDate.is().saturday(1) || fromDate.is().sunday())
                fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
                $('.fromDate-2').html(fromDate.toString('dddd MMMM dS'));
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Next Day Air</td>
            <td>
               <span class="fromDate-3"></span>
               <script>
                  var fromDate = Date.today().addDays(1);
                  if (fromDate.is().saturday() || fromDate.is().sunday())
                   fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
                   $('.fromDate-3').html(fromDate.toString('dddd MMMM dS'));
               </script>
              </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a date library at all for this, it's very straight forward.

It seems goods only travel on business days, so you need a function that adds business days rather than your current algorithm, something like the answers to [*exclude weekends in javascript date calculation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286293/exclude-weekends-in-javascript-date-calculation).

The following does something similar to just add business days, it's only efficient for a small number of days (say 0 to 10).

```js
/* Add business days to a date.
** @param {Date} date - date to start from
** @param {number} deliveryDays - positive integer
** @returns {Date} a new Date object for the delivery date
*/
function getDeliveryDate(date, deliveryDays) {
  // Default delivery is 3 days
  deliveryDays = typeof deliveryDays == 'undefined'? 3 : deliveryDays;
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  var d = new Date(+date);
  // Add days. If land on a Saturday or Sunday, move another day
  while (deliveryDays--) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    if (!(d.getDay() % 6)) ++deliveryDays;
  }
  return d;
}
 
// Some examples
[
 [new Date(2017,0,7),3],  // Saturday start, 3 day delivery
 [new Date(2017,0,8),1],  // Sunday start, 1 day delivery
 [new Date(2017,0,13),1], // Friday start, 1 day delivery
 [new Date(2017,0,13),3], // Friday start, 3 day delivery
 [new Date(2017,0,9), 3], // Monday start, 3 day delivery
 [new Date(2017,0,8), 7]  // Sunday start, 7 day delivery
].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log('Ordered day  : ' + d[0].toString() + 
              '\nDelivery days: ' + d[1] +
              '\nDelivery on  : ' + getDeliveryDate(d[0], d[1]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking at weekends for the final date after adding days, not looking at weekends as the start or (in the case of 3) in between days.  Why not a function like

```
function addDays(date, daysToAdd) {
    for (let i=0; i<daystoAdd; i++) {
        let nextDay = date.addDays(1);
        if (nextDay.is().saturday()) {
            nextDay = date.next().monday();
        }
        date = nextDay;
    }
 return date;
 }
```

Then you just need to call that function for each of your spans:

```
$('.fromDate-1').html(addDays(Date.today(), 3));
```

Is that the problem you were trying to solve?