# exclude holidays and weekends when adding dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to add 10 days to a date excluding holidays and weekends.  Here is the code i am using but i am unable to figure out how to take out the holidays and weekends.  Thanks for any help!!

```
var someDate = item.INITIAL_REQUEST; 
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 10;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
item.FINAL_REQUEST = someDate;
```

Comment: What qualifies as a holiday?

Comment: Why not add one day at a time, and check the result to see whether it's a day you want; if not try the next day, and keep track of how many "good" ones you've seen. You're on your own in determining what "holiday" means however.

Comment: There is also [*DateJS - Do Not Include Weeknds*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517796/datejs-do-not-include-weeknds/41518614#41518614)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in command to do this.

Basically you have to add one date at a time, and test each one for whether it's a holiday or weekend. Weekends are easy:

```
function amIAWeekend(someDate){
  return someDate.getDay() == 6 || someDate.getDay() == 0;
}
```

Testing for a holiday is much harder. The simplest thing to do might be to have a list of holidays in some sort of JSON format, and then for each date run through the list to see if it matches.

Hope this helps get you started!