# Calculate days between two dates once checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I am using below code which will count total days if `cb1` is checked.

If `cb1` is unchecked (default state) weekends will be excluded.

My 1st problem is that it is showing one day less in calculation once `cb1` is checked and 2nd problem is that when `cb1` is unchecked it is not showing any result.

Any help, please. I took reference from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958318/calculate-days-excluding-weekend-and-holiday-in-javascript.).

```
(function () {
     if (getField("cb1").value != "Off") {
         var Start = this.getField("LeaveFrom").value;
         var End = this.getField("LeaveEnd").value;
         var dStart = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy H:MM:SS", Start + " 0:00:00");
         var dEnd = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy H:MM:SS", End + " 0:00:00");
         var diff = dEnd.getTime() - dStart.getTime();
         var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
         var days = Math.floor(diff/oneDay);
         event.value = days;
     } else {
         var start = this.getField("LeaveFrom").value; // get the start date value
         var end = this.getField("LeaveEnd").value; // get the end date value
         var start =util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy H:MM:SS", start + " 0:00:00");
         var end = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy H:MM:SS", end + " 0:00:00");

         event.value = dateDifference(start, end);

         function dateDifference(start, end) {
             if (end < start) return -1;
             // Copy date objects so don't modify originals
             var s = new Date(+start);
             var e = new Date(+end);

             // Get the difference in whole days
             var totalDays = Math.round((e - s) / 8.64e7);
             // Get the difference in whole weeks
             var wholeWeeks = totalDays / 7 | 0;
             // Estimate business days as number of whole weeks * 5
             var days = wholeWeeks * 5;
             // If not even number of weeks, calc remaining weekend days
             if (totalDays % 7) {
                 s.setDate(s.getDate() + wholeWeeks * 7);
                 while (s < e) {
                     s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);
                     // If day isn't a Friday or Saturday, add to business days
                     if (s.getDay() != 5 && s.getDay() != 6) {
                         ++days;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return days;
         }
     }
})();
```

Comment: are `var Start` and `var End` in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

Comment: Yes. dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: drop the `+`. `var s = new Date(start);`

Comment: removed +. used var s = new Date(start); but nothing changed

Comment: what are the values of `start` and `end` that are being passed into `dateDifference`?

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: I am missing something in my code, so it is not counting start day. That's why one day less.