# How to calculate hour between start date and end date excluding the weekend in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

In my application i have start datetime picker and end datetime picker. any idea how to calculate hours between two dates excluding weekend in AngularJS.

Comment: Are you using any library like `moment`??

Comment: Go over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313068/5247200), then it should be straightforward to convert days to hours. And, like @AbhisarTripathi advised, `moment.js` is very helpful when doing non-standard work with data/time in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will count only business workday hours for you using `moment.js` library -:

```
function calculateWorkDays(start, end) {
  if (moment(end, "YYYY-MM-DD").isBefore(start, "YYYY-MM-DD")) {
    return null;
  }
  var duration = moment.duration(
    moment(end, "YYYY-MM-DD").diff(moment(start, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
  );
  var hours = duration.asHours();
  var days = moment.duration(
    moment(end, "YYYY-MM-DD").diff(moment(start, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
  )._data.days;
  for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
    if (
      [6, 7].includes(
        moment(start, "YYYY-MM-DD")
          .add(i, "days")
          .day()
      )
    ) {
      hours -= 24;
    }
  }
  console.log(hours);
  return hours;
}
```