# how can i count the range between 2 dates without counting the weekend in javascript

Tags: javascript, yii, datepicker, datediff, weekend

i want to calculate the range between 2 dates without counting weekend in javascript. i have some code that already count the range between them. but i'm stuck with the weekend part. date inputed by CJuiDatePicker in YII framework

```
    <script>
    function calcDay(dt1, dt2, range){

    var msec1 = dt1;
    var date1 = new date(msec1);
    var msec2 = dt2;
    var date2 = new date(msec2);

    if(date1>0 || date2>0){
    range.val(isFinite(Math.round(date2-date1)/86400000) || 0);
    }
    };
    </script>
```

86400000 is day in millisecond

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find day difference between two dates (excluding weekend days)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464268/find-day-difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekend-days)

Comment: thanks for replying, i have tried it before but still got no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my own solution, but i forgot to share it. this is how i make it

```
function myUpdate(dt1, dt2,range){
        var msec1 = dt1;            
        var date1 =  new Date(msec1);
        var msec2 = dt2;
        var date2 =  new Date(msec2);
        var diff = (isFinite(Math.round (date2 - date1) / 86400000) && Math.round (date2 - date1) / 86400000 || 0);
        var wEnd=0;

        if(date1>0 || date2>0){
                for(var i=0; i<=diff; i++){
                    if(date1.getDay() ==6 || date1.getDay()==0){
                        wEnd = wEnd + 1;
                    }
                    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                }
            }
        range.val(Math.round((diff-wEnd)+1));
    };
```

first u should count the different date, then the `date1` will be check if it is sunday or saturday. then `date1` will be added 1 till the value of `date1` is equal to `date2`. if `date1` is/are saturday or sunday, `wEnd` will gain 1. so u can substract `diff` with `wEnd`. hope this can help u guys

Answer (score 0):

The function you'll need is getUTCDay().

the pseudo code would be as follows:
1 - determine full weeks (days/7 truncated) 
2 - calculate weekday/weekend: 2 * result = weekend days, 5 * result = weekdays.
3 - after that,  remainder and starting day of week will determine the 1 or 2 additional days

Hope that helps, let me know if you need the javascript,
- John

Edited, as requested.  NOTE: tweaked your original for testing, you should spot the needed changes to restore.

```
function calcDay(dt1, dt2, range)
{
    var msec1 = "October 13, 2014 11:13:00";
    var date1 = new Date(msec1);
    var msec2 = "October 13, 2013 11:13:00";
    var date2 = new Date(msec2);

    var days;
    var wdays;
    var startday;
    var nLeft;

    // neither should be zero
    if(date1>0 && date2>0) {
        days = Math.round( Math.abs((date2-date1)/86400000) );
        wdays = Math.round(days / 7) * 5;
        nLeft = days % 7;
        startday = (date1 > date2) ? date2.getUTCDay() : date1.getUTCDay();

        if (startday < 2) {
            wdays += Math.max(nLeft+startday-1,0);
        } else if (startday == 6) {
            wdays += Math.max(nLeft-2,0);
        } else if (nLeft > (7-startday)) {
            wdays += (nLeft-2)
        } else {
            wdays += Math.min(nLeft, 6-startday)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can i have the javascript? Cz i hv tried a lot but still cant get the result

Comment: @Trainee - there you go - NOTE: it's written to count weekdays, for weekends, you can either subtract from total, or figure the reconciliation yourself (btw - weekdays is the more complicated, why I supplied that)