# Exclude holidays between 2 Dates

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched all over the Internet, and I finally this piece of code in
[Weekend Exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464268/find-day-difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekend-days?noredirect=1&lq=1).

OR

```
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
      iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } else {
      iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
  }
```

I have no idea how to add codes to exclude the holiday.  I understand I have to create an array to store the holidays, but after that I stuck at the point. I need your help, much appreciated.

Comment: You wanna exclude the weekends alone or holidays too?

Comment: I wanna exclude both weekends and holidays.

Comment: In that case, you must know the dates of holidays. Do you have that information?

Comment: Just let say (2017-06-25, 2017-06-26, 2017-06-27) as holidays.

Comment: Got it... Check it out.

Comment: Mine is javascript, not php :D

Comment: That's PHP bro. Check out the answer.

Comment: No No I mean I wanna do in javascript, not php.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! Bro, sorry, I am terribly sorry! Guess I am not okay. Lemme take a break. LoL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the holidays array and check if the date falls in the range and also check if the holiday is on Saturday or Sunday in which case it is already counted. Below is the modified example.

```
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2, holidays) { // input given as Date objects
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0, i;
    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed
    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
      iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } else {
      iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust; // take into account both days on weekend

    for(i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
      if(holidays[i] >= dDate1 && holidays[i] <= dDate2 && holidays[i].getDay() != 0 && holidays[i].getDay() != 6) {
        iDateDiff--;
      }
    }

    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
  }

var holidays = [ new Date(2017, 5, 2), new Date(2017, 5, 3), new Date(2017, 5, 4), new Date(2017, 5, 5) ];

calcBusinessDays(new Date(2017,1,1), new Date(), holidays);
// returns 93
```